# Print Full Content of Picturebox C#

Tags: c#

So I know that you can print the image content of a picture box using:

```
private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(pictureBox1.Image, 0, 0);
}
```

To print the background image, I will need to change to:

```
e.Graphics.DrawImage(pictureBox1.BackgroundImage, 0, 0);
```

Question is how do you print both?

Thanks,

Comment: What do you mean by print both,  do you want the pictures merged on thesame image? Or you want to print them one after the other.

Comment: @ozioma both merged onto the same image. I think the question is already answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do the background first:

```
private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(pictureBox1.BackgroundImage, 0, 0);
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(pictureBox1.Image, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: Will this print both on one sheet? I'm interested in both.

Comment: Well, if you print the background first, the `Image` will be printed on top of the background one.

Comment: @NothinRandom I tried drawing it on a form and it worked, just give it a try on a sheet.

Comment: @Darkrifts Oh ok. I was under the impression that it would print one at a time. Thanks!

Comment: Until it completes, it should just add on, unless I'm mistaken.

Answer (score 2):

Manipulate it as you wish..

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap (500,500);
pictureBox1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, pictureBox1.DisplayRectangle);
bmp.Save("C:\\abcd.jpg");
```

Comment: Hey Abdul. So how would this help in printing background image and image at the same time?

Comment: it prints both at the same time.. you get a combined image

Comment: In fact `DrawToBitmap` __also__ combines both images with anything you __draw__ on the surface in the `Paint` event..! Of course you don't need to save it; just `DrawImage` the `bmp` in a `PrintPage` event. - Also note that it combines the images as they are seen, i.e. without zooming and with the same dpi resolution!